# My vowel counter won't count in VB

Tags: vb.net

I need to make a vowel then word counter in vb and it will not work. i have just tried the vowel bit for now but its not working. Any ideas ?

```
    Dim analsyedtext As String
    Dim lettercount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    lettercount = 0
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the text to be analysed.")
    analsyedtext = Console.ReadLine()
    If analsyedtext = "a" Or "e" Or "i" Or "o" Or "u" Then
        lettercount = lettercount + 1
    End If
    Console.Writeline("The number of vowels is,{0}", lettercount)
End Sub
```

Comment: thats not how the [Or Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06s37a7f.aspx) works.  Why the random tag?

Comment: You need to compare the characters, not the whole string. Your code only increases lettercount if the user entered a *one-letter text* containing a vowel. You will need a loop for that (or clever use of [`Enumerable.Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038(v=vs.100).aspx), but that might be too advanced for a beginner).

Comment: Look at each letter in `analsyedtext` (sic)

Comment: you ask the user to enter "some text" which can be a word or *War and Peace* which you stored in `analsyedtext`. Loop thru is using a for loop and `.SubString`

Comment: you stored the *full text* in `analsyedtext` but you need to count the *characters* which make up that text.  You have a whole slew of keywords you can research now: substring, Or, for loop, character

Comment: @Plutonix Yes I've reserched charecter and thats what ive used . I am really confused and you seem to be confusing me more. Will something like this work ? Dim spaceCount, lettercount As Integer
 spaceCount= 0
 lettercount = 0
 Dim s As String = " 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 a b c"
 For Each c As Char In s
    If c = " " Then
        spaceCount+= 1
    Else
        lettercount += 1
    End If

Comment: I've got it working but now need it to work using a full document e.g with spaces for paragraph's Anybody know how?

Answer (score 3):

```
' My preferred function
Private Function VowelCount(str As String) As Integer
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    Return (From letter In str.ToLower().ToCharArray()
            Where vowels.Contains(letter)
            Select letter).Count()
End Function
' This tests all of the functions and Asserts they're identical output
Sub Main()
    For Each itm In {"this", "is", "some sort of", "a test that we're doing"}
        Dim vowelNum = VowelCount(itm)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", itm, vowelNum)
        Debug.Assert(vowelNum = VowelCount2(itm) AndAlso
                     vowelNum = VowelCount3(itm) AndAlso
                     vowelNum = VowelCount4(itm) AndAlso
                     vowelNum = VowelCount5(itm))
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
' Identical to above, different syntax
Private Function VowelCount2(str As String) As Integer
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    Return str.ToLower().ToCharArray().Where(Function(ltr As Char) vowels.Contains(ltr)).Count()
End Function
' Uses another function IsVowel that does the same thing as vowels.Contains()
Private Function VowelCount3(str As String) As Integer
    Dim vowelsInStr As New List(Of Char)
    For Each letter As Char In str.ToLower().ToCharArray()
        If IsVowel(letter) Then
            vowelsInStr.Add(letter)
        End If
    Next
    Return vowelsInStr.Count
End Function
' Different since this doesn't first put vowels into an IEnumerable and then count the vowels, it only does the count
Private Function VowelCount4(str As String) As Integer
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    Dim count As Integer
    For Each letter In str.ToLower().ToCharArray()
        If IsVowel2(letter) Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function
' Same as above but uses a For loop instead of For Each
Private Function VowelCount5(str As String) As Integer
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim letters() As Char = str.ToLower().ToCharArray()
    For i = 0 To letters.Length - 1
        If IsVowel2(letters(i)) Then
            count += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function

Private Function IsVowel(ltr As Char) As Boolean
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    Return vowels.Contains(ltr)
End Function

Private Function IsVowel2(ltr As Char) As Boolean
    Dim vowels() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    For Each vowel As Char In vowels
        If vowel = ltr Then
            Return True
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think I'm at this level yet and I don't understand, Do you have any way of fixing mine or helping me too so I can become a better programmer. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: Added some examples which simplify, but once you become familiar with `LINQ` it seems more and more simple.

Comment: Thanks but is there any way of mine working. It seems to me like it should

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Just realized there is more work for you to do, to get each individual letter. But assuming you get to the point where `analsyedtext` is one letter:

```
Select Case analsyedtext
    Case "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
        lettercount += 1
    Case Else
        ' Do nothing
End Select
```

Comment: How do I get it to do just 1 letter?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is examine the input string one character at a time.

You can extract one character at a time by using the [SubString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function like this (instead of your `If..Then..End If` piece of code):

```
For i = 0 To analsyedtext.Length - 1
    Dim c = analsyedtext.Substring(i, 1)
    If c = "a" OrElse c = "e" OrElse c = "i" OrElse c = "o" OrElse c = "u" Then
        lettercount = lettercount + 1
    End If
Next
```

Notice how it starts from zero and goes to `analsyedtext.Length - 1` - that is because the first character has an index of zero.

Comment: Thanks, how do you do this for a whole document, with paragraph spaces.

Comment: I've got it working but now need it to work using a full document e.g with spaces for paragraph's Anybody know how?

Comment: @user5423489 You put the whole document into `analysedText`. It will work just the same. If you want to count words, then you need to look at spaces. Paragraphs (on Windows PCs) are generally separated by two characters in sequence: Chr(13) and Chr(10). However, it it likely to be sufficient to just count the occurrences of Chr(10).

Comment: Ok I got that but what if the user accidentally typed 2 or 3 spaces won't it count them as words. and i tried copying and pasting a word document and the program crashes.